# CharAt in Java 8

Tags: java, char, character

The charAt isn't working... It's returning the hash code and not the value of a part in a structure.

Ex.: charAt(0) where is '1' is returning 49 and not 1

What Am I able to do?!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. It's not clear what your code is.

Comment: It's correct.  It's returning the character '1', which when treated as an `int` has the value 49.

Comment: Your code is casting the returned value to an int... cast it back to `char` and you'll see `1`

Comment: The method is defined as [`char charAt(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-), with a return type of **`char`**, so why are you assigning it to a *numeric* variable, e.g. `int`???

Answer (score 1):

It >>is<< working.  It is returning that character as a `char` which (presumably) you are assigning to an `int` and printing.  The numeric value of the ASCII / Unicode codepoint for the character `'1'` is `49`.  If you want to print / display this as a character, cast the `int` to a `char`.  (Or don't assign it to an `int` in the first place.)

For the record, the hashCode value returned by `Character` is identical to the character value.  Strictly speaking a `char` doesn't have a hashCode because it is a primitive value, and primitives don't have methods.

Comment: To add to your answer it's probably also worth mentioning that a chars int value is its [ascii value](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)

Comment: Done that. Thanks.